# Gnuplot - Draw grid behind rectangles

Tags: gnuplot

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how to draw the grid lines behind the rectangles in Gnuplot. Does anyone know how to achieve this? Here is the code I've tried so far, with an image for quick view of the result:

```
set nokey
set grid
set size ratio -1
set xrange[0:10]
set yrange[0:10]
set style fill transparent solid 0.5
set xtics 1
set ytics 1
set obj 1 rect from 0,0 to 3,2
set obj 2 rect from 0,0 to 2,3
plot 0
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `set grid back` ?

Comment: I did, but that didn't worked :( However looking at your suggestion, it just hit me that I could use `set grid front`, and that worked for showing the grid in front of the rectangles. But unfortunately the second rectangle is hiding the first one. So still not 100% what I need, but thanks anyway! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perhaps this might help:
`set obj 1 rect from 0,0 to 3,2 fillstyle empty`

Comment: That was just what I was looking for. Thanks!!